# CKEditor 4: Can I define multiple plugin directories?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Is it possible for me to configure `CKEditor` to `"search"` for plugins in more than one directory?

I'm including the base `CKEditor` files using `Bower` and would like to keep my custom config and additional plugins outside of the bower_components folder.

From the docs I can see that it's possible to [enable extra plugins](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraPlugins) easily enough but I think it assumes that the plugins are all contained within the main plugins folder - hopefully I'm wrong!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.resourceManager-method-addExternal) is what you're looking for:

```
// Loads a plugin from '/myplugin/samples/plugin.js'.
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'sample', '/myplugins/sample/' );

// Loads a plugin from '/myplugin/samples/my_plugin.js'.
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'sample', '/myplugins/sample/', 'my_plugin.js' );

// Loads a plugin from '/myplugin/samples/my_plugin.js'.
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'sample', '/myplugins/sample/my_plugin.js', '' );
```

Once the plugin is defined, you can use it, i.e. via [`config.extraPlugins`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraPlugins):

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraPlugins: 'sample'
} );
```